# jQuery, Javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a requirement to extract numeric characters from the alphanumeric string. Like the alphanumeric string may be like:

`cmq-1a,tq-2.1a,vq-001,hq-001a...`

From the aphanumeric string i need to extract the numeric and I need to get the maximum out of those numbers. Please suggest how to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself already? If you have, post the code. If you haven't, maybe you should. We're here to point you in the right direction, not *do* the work for you.

Comment: What does this question have to do with JQuery?

Comment: @Royi Namir: no, I've seen 0...

Comment: Is "2.1" (from within your example string) to be treated as a numeric character "2" followed by a non-numeric character "." followed by another numeric "1" and thus be parsed as two separate numbers? Or as the decimal number "2.1"?

Comment: Given this string as an input, what's the output supposed to be? Should the `001` remain as a `001` (with leading zeroes), or as `1`?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should help:

```
var str = "cmq-1a,tq-2.1a,vq-001,hq-001a";

var max = str.match(/\d+/g).sort(function (a, b) {
    return (window.parseInt(a, 10) < window.parseInt(b, 10));
})[0];

// max = 2
```

This will extract all the positive integers from the `String` and return the one with the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand cleary, but you seeking some like this ??

`"cmq-1a,tq-2.1a,vq-001,hq-001a".replace(/\D/g, '')`

Comment: <HTML>
       <HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
    {
    var string2="MerlinQ-1B"
    parsestring2=string2.replace(/[-A-Za-z]/g, "") 
    
    alert(parsestring2);
    }
    </script>
       </HEAD>
       
       
    <BODY>
       <H1>Hi</H1>
       <P>This is very minimal "hello world" HTML document.</P>
       <button onclick=check()>Click</button>
       
    </BODY>
    </HTML>

This will give the numeric characters.

Comment: @Chandu Sorry, I didn't get your point...

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
var input = 'cmq-1a,tq-2.1a,vq-001,hq-001a';

var temp = input.split(/\D/);
var output = [];

for (var i=0, len = temp.length; i<len;i++){
    if (temp[i] !== ''){

        output.push(parseInt(temp[i],10));
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gbvT6/1/).